# Why am I not able to use -o or --format with ps command to control the output format?

Tags: linux, git-bash, ps

I want to print certain columns only from `ps` output that is PID, PPID, command, memory utilization and CPU utilization columns.

when I run `ps` command I get the following output.
[image]

Now I only want some columns from this output so I use -o flag as mentioned in this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ps-command-in-linux-with-examples/).

But I am getting this error.

[image]

I don't understand where is the problem. I have also tried usin `--help` and it is not showing `-o` flag. So I am confused here.

[image]

I am using the **windows** operating system. And using **Git Bash terminal** to run all these Linux commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git Bash is a terminal for Windows that emulates the Linux bash (shell) functionality. It is not 100% compatible to a "real" bash shell. As you've empirically seen, its `ps` executable doesn't support all the flags you're used to from Linux. The `--help` option will show you what flags are supported.

Answer (score 1):

> Hello
>
> Maybe put 2 things together, ps and grep? Then try this...

```
ps | grep -o -E "^[ 0-9]{1,9}"
```

> ...and is this working on your system?
> ( The Space in [ ] is important )

Comment: Thanks For the answer. But this is a workaround to get the output. I wanted to use `-o` flag with ps not with grep. This works on my system and gives me the process id.

Comment: But your "ps" is not able to put out things with -o. Linux is /proc in other words: The Kernel. Take a look with: ls /proc. And there are many ways to "Rome". If you dont like grep hide it with an alias. Thats of course another workaround. ```alias 'pspids'='ls /proc | grep -o -E "^[ 0-9]{1,9}" | sort -n'```